# ClientClosedError: The client is closed error in Node.js with Docker and Redis

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I have a Node.js code. While running this code, i have an error.

This error is

> ClientClosedError: The client is closed

My redis run on docker called redis1.

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 6379
});




client.on("error", error => {
    if(error) {
        console.error("ERROR***",error);
    }else {
        console.log("Redis connect.");
    }
});


//SET
client.set("user_name", "Furkan", (err, msg) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error("Error while connecting redis", err);
    }else {
        console.log(msg);
    } 
})
```

Furhermore; when i was run this code, dont log in terminal any code. Namely when i was run this code, didnt log in terminal *ERROR**** , *Redis Connected* or *Error while connecting redis*.

These logs is exists in my code.

[this link](https://medium.com/geekculture/using-redis-with-docker-and-nodejs-express-71dccd495fd3) is reference for me.

How can i fix this code.?

Answer (score 4):

You should add in your code before the client code or set code,

```
(async () => {
   client.connect();
})();
```

block.

Answer (score 0):

you have to running redis-server on docker.

```
docker run -d --name redis-stack-server -p 6379:6379 redis/redis-stack-server:latest
```